# Refresh DataGrid without freezing the application (asynchronous)

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, datagrid, refresh

I have a DataGrid filled with 'verifiable objects'. A verification of one object takes about 150ms.

A row looks like this:

[image]

If I verify one object it can be valid or invalid:

[image]

[image]

I can verify all object in the DataGrid.
Currently I refresh the datagrid gui after all object are verified (the datagrid is during the verification disabled). But it can take minutes if the datagrid is filled with thousands of objects, but the user should see the progress. My idea: refresh the datagrid after every verification. But a refresh takes long (like 100-300ms)... if I have 500 objects in my datagrid it has to refresh 500 times and during a refresh the application GUI freezes... basically the gui is during the verification permanent frozen

Is there a way to just refresh ONE row? or: is it possible to refresh the datagrid asynchronous?
I don't care if the datagrid freezes (it is disabled anyway), but the application shouldn't freeze.

**Edit:** I am using a DataBinding to an ObservableCollection. After each verification I trigger the PropertyChanged event (INotifyPropertyChanged). Although it doesn't get updated after each verification...

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky business because you can't refresh the grid asynchronously because that means that you would be doing so on a separate thread, and the only thread that should be updating the UI is the UI thread.

However, if you have a data source associated with your grid, you can use a `System.ComponentModel.BindingList` for your data source.  Then you can update the binding list on a separate thread, and this will result in only the updated rows or cells being affected.  Here is an example.

This is a class-level declaration/assignment:

```
Private myList As New System.ComponentModel.BindingList(Of String)(New List(Of String)({"First", "Second", "Third"}))
```

Here's the form load event handler:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    DataGridView1.DataSource = myList
End Sub
```

Then you could do this inside whatever method does your main code.  I'm using the button click event handler:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    myList.RaiseListChangedEvents = False

    Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub()
                              Me.Invoke(Sub() myList.Add("Fourth"))
                          End Sub)

    myList.RaiseListChangedEvents = True
    myList.ResetBindings()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us some code for how you populate the DataGrid?

Typically you do not want to refresh the whole list. Instead you should be using data bindings and property change notifications to refresh/update only the values that have changed.

This would be achieved by having the validity column bound to a validity property on you data object (which implements INotifyPropertyChanged hopefully) and then updating this property upon completion of your validation check. It's hard to be any more specific without seeing some code.